# Specify the root for of PSR-0 namespace in composer

Tags: php

I current have the following composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "App": "app/" }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate a class in the app folder, but the autoloader is looking for:

```
/var/www/framework/app//App/App.php
```

Obviously the second parameter is the folder containing the namespace rather than the root of the namespace. How can I make it load:

```
/var/www/framework/app/App.php
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which class you are trying to instanciate?

Comment: new \App\App()

which results in the above path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to rename the folder from `app` to `App` and set

```
"psr-0": { "App": "." }
```

I guess else you need a custom autoloader. However, I recommend to follow some proven use-cases:

```
src/App/App.php
```

with

```
"psr-0": { "App": "src" }
```

Looks curious, but I must say, that I would never call a namespace or class (or even both) just `App` ;) It doesn't say anything and with aliasing (`use MyApplication as App`) there is no reason anymore to write as short identifiers as possible.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. My App class was actually an extension of Slim Framework Slim class, and the rest of the namespace contains controllers etc.

Comment: This is one of the clearer recommendations I've seen but it still seems pointless to me to have `src/MyApp` when `MyApp` is the only folder in `src`...even if all the app code is in `src` I'd rather put the app-specific libraries in `src/lib`. Would it be legitimate to put the `MyApp` folder inside `vendor`? I'd prefer to have my app-specific libraries in `lib` with no extra subdir, and 3rd-party libraries in `vendor`, but as far as I can tell that's not possible without writing your own autoloader for app-specific libraries.

Comment: "own code in `vendor`": No :) `vendor` is composers folder and also should never be versionized. That you have this single `MyApp`-folder in `src` comes from `PSR-0`, that says, that every namespace must directly map onto a path. One solution is to _not_ declare the folder as `PSR-0`-compliant (see my third code-snippet `"psr-0": { "App": "src" }` ;)). A custom loader class is possible, but imo not worth the effort See http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap